# plugin settings - uploading multiple files with a single button

Tags: plugin-development, input

My plugin settings' page has a

```
<input type='file' name='adm_uploads' multiple />
```

button which allows my browser to select multiple files as expected.

All goes well except that in my callback $_FILES only contains the array corresponding to the last file from the browser' selection. It looks like the other files are not sent.

Any idea of what could cause the issue?

Comment: I think you need to be more specific. Maybe add some code?

Comment: I'd gladly add any details. What exactly do you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<input type='file' name='adm_uploads[]' multiple />
```

Comment: I had to do just that to be able to select multiple files, although I did not have a '[]' in the name. Is this key?

Comment: Yes this ensures that you can create an array.